# flex array collection

Tags: apache-flex

```
public function groupListRH(event:ResultEvent):void {
    groupsList=event.result as ArrayCollection;
}

public function show(event):void {
    selectedItem=(event.target as ComboBox).selectedIndex; 
    Alert.show(selectedItem.toString().groupId);
}

<mx:ComboBox dataProvider="{groupsList}" labelField="groupName" id="grpLst"width="150" prompt="Select One Group" change="show(event);" focusIn="init();" />
```

I'm not getting like this ...how can I get groupId (exact id which I'm getting into arraycollection thru remoteobject) of selected GroupName?

Answer (score 2):

In your `show()` method, you convert the selectedItem to a string before you grab your `groupId`.  You need to switch it around so that you retrieve your `groupId` from the `selectedItem` first.

```
public function show(event):void {
    Alert.show(selectedItem.groupId.toString());
}

<mx:ComboBox id="grpLst"
    width="150"
    dataProvider="{groupsList}"
    labelField="groupName"
    prompt="Select One Group"
    change="show(event);"
/>
```